# RXJava repeat request if response is not successful and continue stream

Tags: android, stream, rx-java, retrywhen

I need to make a request to a webserver and the server usually returns a reference code that i use in the stream. But sometimes the server is busy and returns an error indicating that it's busy so that i have to retry in a few moments.

```
public static Single<List<iIB>> run()
{
    //First retrieve reference code from IB
    return IBRepository.getInstance().getReferenceCode()
                .doOnSuccess(s -> Log.d(AppConstants.AppTag, "Success: " + s))
                .doOnError(s -> Log.d(AppConstants.AppTag, "Error: " + s))

            //Once reference code is retrieved, make second request to get XML report as string
        .flatMap((Function<String, SingleSource<String>>) referenceCode -> IBRepository.getInstance().getXMLReport(referenceCode))
        
        ...
}


/**
 * This method makes the first request to IB to get the reference code for the flex query in case of success
 * Sometimes server is busy and ask to retry the request in a few moments so we return an error indicating the cause
 * @return an observable string containing the reference code to download the XMLParser report in IB
 */
public Single<String> getReferenceCode()
{
    final String REF_CODE = "ReferenceCode";
    final String STATUS = "Status";
    final String FAIL = "Fail";
    final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "ErrorMessage";

    return Single.fromObservable(_Volley.getInstance().postRxVolley(IBConstants.QUERY_REQUEST_URL)
            .flatMap((Function<Result, ObservableSource<String>>) Response::processResultResponse)
            .flatMapSingle((Function<String, SingleSource<String>>) xmlResponse ->
            {
                Document xmlDocument = XMLParser.convertStringToXMLDocument(xmlResponse);

                if(xmlDocument == null)
                    return Single.error(new Throwable("Error with DOM XML Library"));
                else if(!XMLParser.getSingleValueFromTag(xmlDocument, STATUS, 0).contains(FAIL))
                    return Single.just(XMLParser.getSingleValueFromTag(xmlDocument, REF_CODE, 0));
                else
                    return Single.error(new Throwable(XMLParser.getSingleValueFromTag(xmlDocument, ERROR_MESSAGE, 0)));
            }));
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is to retry the call to getReferenceCode() after some time if that method returns an error. Could this be achievable using RxJava operators?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use RxJava2 `retryWhen` operator and set the condition you want to retry your api call.

- http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html

You can check this blog for your reference

- https://pamartinezandres.com/rxjava-2-exponential-backoff-retry-only-when-internet-is-available-5a46188ab175